# Получение некорректного значения input type='number' при изменении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

Есть поле для ввода и нужно получить строку, которая в него вводится.

```js
$("#test").on("change", function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='number' id="test">
```

Все работает, но, если я копирую и вставляю строку некорректного формата, например такую `123231,3232.00`, то `console.log()` возвращает пустую строку. Как мне получить именно ту строку, которую вставил в поле, не меняя `type='number'` на `type='text'`.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге пока решил проблему следующим образом

```js
$("#test").on("paste", function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
      $this.select();
      console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
  }, 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='number' id="test">
```

Все оказалось довольно просто, хоть и криво. Возможно, кто-то предложит более интересный вариант.